# How is the restful API secured?

Tags: api, security, rest

In order to access the API securely what do I need to do?

Is it as simple as using `https` and letting my CMS manage session authentication?

Comment: Have you implemented the RESTFul APIs calls using https ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether or not https is used would be dependent on the CMS, but this is certainly recommended. Other than making sure the Access AJAX Api permission is set up for a particular CMS user, you will also need to pass a user api key that is assigned to the CiviCRM contact record associated with that CMS user.

**Details at:** http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/REST+interface#RESTinterface-SettinguptousetheRESTAPI

Answer (score 8):

The REST API requires that you specify the site key and an API key.  Details can be found [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/REST+interface#RESTinterface-SettinguptousetheRESTAPI).

Comment: ...beat me to it.